# Generic TypeScript function that instantiates classes

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I set out to write a generic TypeScript function that takes a class constructor as an argument, as well as any arguments required by the constructor, and returns a new instance of the class. One of my requirements is that the return type and constructor argument types must be inferred by the compiler.

After some trial and error I came up with a working version that seems to do what I need (see below). But, is there a better way to achieve this?

```
function instantiate<Params extends any[], Instance>(
    ctor: new (...args: Params) => Instance, ...args: Params
) {
    return new ctor(...args);
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Circle {
    constructor(public radius: number) {}
}

class Rectangle {
    constructor(public width: number, public height: number) {}
}

const circle = instantiate(Circle, 5);
const rectangle = instantiate(Rectangle, 3, 7);
```

[Try on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMBnKBDMsNQKYA8AChgE4YC2qieAHvmACbVYCeA2gLoA0iAkmkyQ8APgAUAKETTE0OKQBciMHgDuiMQDptZAOaolJclQCUiALwj+grBDy9tmvQcRHKqCWYDeUmaTxQIKRIKupypFo6pPomANwSAL4SEhAANhio1ADCMKRpeIg+MrII6KQg4WIADiAARqkwEIjkjDAgLmAgFLV4pN5JSSnpmYgASnjQWLqpBUUyEKVQ5ZU19Y2IqjCMUAAWSp3dvbyrDU07eDC6O1D7XT19hQPJC4KyufkWyDbYMLh4Yjk8jNeABWOIpRbNCZCaYFcxfdBYHD4MTjSZgWG8ADMvAA7OCgA)

Comment: This seems really perfect to me. I wasted the last two hours trying to find a better (or cleaner) solution, but I can't. I explored a way to infer additional parameters such as class fields not expected by the constructor, but at the end it feels quite useless. Good job, indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it simpler in terms of your use of generic types by making use of the [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterst) and [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) utility types:

```
function instantiate<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
    ctor: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>
): InstanceType<T> {
    return new ctor(...args);
}
```

Comment: I just edited the type parameter names in my question to avoid masking the built-in InstanceType utility type. I like your approach. It looks very clean. However, I was trying to avoid adding an explicit return type annotation. One of the challenges was to see if I could get TypeScript to infer the return type for me. That being said, on the job I would use your approach since it's very clear.

Comment: @RichardGieg yes I was also trying not to specify the return type, but that would have involved more complex type inference